# Can't use cfg (type "...aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws".Config") as type (type ...) in argument to dynamodb.New

Tags: go, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create a Go program that creates a Put Pre-signed URL and saves into DynamoDB, using the SDK V2. I was able to figure it out only how to create the pre-signed url, but not how to save into DynamoDB, because the following error is happening:

```
./main.go:67:24: cannot use cfg (type "Test2/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws".Config) as type "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws".Config in argument to dynamodb.New
```

And this is the code:

```
package main

import (
  "time"
  // "fmt"

  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/endpoints"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
  "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"

)


type Bucket struct {
  Name string
}

// Using the SDK's default configuration, loading additional config
// and credentials values from the environment variables, shared
// credentials, and shared configuration files
var cfg, err = external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()

// Description
var bucket Bucket

func main() {
    err = envconfig.Process("bucket", &bucket)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    } else if len(cfg.Region) > 0 {
        // Set Region to us-east-1 as default.
        cfg.Region = endpoints.UsEast1RegionID
    }

    url, err := createPresignedPutURL()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    _, err = createNewExtraction(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}

func createPresignedPutURL() (string, error) {
    svc := s3.New(cfg)
    req := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("garimpo-extractions"),
        Key: aws.String("uuid"),
    })

    url, _, err := req.PresignRequest(15 * time.Minute)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return url, nil
}

func createNewExtraction(url string) (string, error) {
    svc := dynamodb.New(cfg) // ERROR IS HERE
    return "", nil
    // req := svc.ScanRequest(&dynamodb.ScanInput{
    //     TableName: aws.String("extractions-development"),
    // })

    // // // Fire request with req.Send().
    // res, err := req.Send(); if err != nil {
    //     return "", err
    // }
    // return res, nil
}
```

I'm not really understanding what is going on. I'm using the `cfg` to create a connection to s3, and is working, but when I try to create a connection with DynamoDB, it fails.

Comment: The two cfg types are inconsistent because their package path isn't the same, one is imported from the vendor folder, the other isn't. Try re-vendoring all your deps: delete the Test2/vendor folder and rerun then your dependency manager.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: How do I know what exactly?